# Remove Injected Script in Crontab

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script, virus, cron

I have a Server installed with Ubuntu 16.4.5 LTS. When I check crontab, there is a script that download from anonymous website and run the script.

I try to remove the schedule but the script installed again in crontab.

This is the script that downloaded from crontab. can you tell me what is the name of this script and how to remove from my server.

[image: crontab list]

[script file](https://pastebin.com/X2EK5LXb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: The script downloads and run some kind of miner.

Comment: I'd suggest you to examine function c() in the malicious script. It makes a number of changes to a cron schedule.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you remove it from one place, and due to the fact that it installs in other places as well, it just re-installs. The problem is, as  montonero suggests, indeed in the function `c` in the script.

To remove it from your system, look at:
    /usr/local/bin/dns
    /etc/crontab
    /etc/cron.d/root
    /etc/cron.d/apache
    /var/spool/cron/root
    /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
    /etc/ld.so.preload
    /etc/cron.hourly/
    /etc/cron.monthly/
    /etc/cron.daily/

The last three will have a file called `oanacroner`, that you must look at.

You may also look at function `b` in the file and see which of the processes mentioned there are running (in the `pkill`-lines and the `ps aux | grep`-lines)

At the end of function `b`, there are some services and communication with specific hosts that you will want to terminate as well. Even though it is not in this script, you will want to look at your inetd or xinetd config as well.

And finally, `wget http://yxarsh.shop/0` and examine that one as well.

When you start cleaning, `ifconfig down` your network interfaces.

Good luck.

Comment: wow... that is a detailed step to solve this issue. i'll try it. thx